# css issue in datepicker in infopath form - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, css

my InfoPath distorted date picker

[image]

I am getting a message

> CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch defaultcss.ashx.

I have no customization on this apart from the default master page and InfoPath form.